# No data POST (Laravel 5.5)

Tags: php, post, laravel-5.5

Developed the project on the local After transferred to the host.
Everything work fine except for the fact that the frontent part does not work POST. In the backend everything works fine!

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator; 
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Page;
use App\People;
use App\Portfolio;
use App\Service;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function execute( Request $request ) {

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
            var_dump($_POST);die; //NOTHING!!!
        }

        if( $request->isMethod('post') ) {  
            ......
            dd( $request->all() ); //NOTHING!!!

            //Validate
            ......
            return redirect()->route('home')
                ->withErrors($validator)->withInput($request->all()); 
        }


        return view('frontendsite.index', [
        ....
        ])->render();

}
```

My route:

```
Route::group( ['middleware'=>['web'] ], function() { 
    Route::match(['get','post'], '/', ['uses'=>'IndexController@execute', 'as'=>'home']);

    Route::auth();
});
```

No $_POST. On the local all is well and in the backend everything works fine!

```
for backend I have rout like this:
Route::group( [ 'prefix'=>'admin', 'middleware'=>['auth'] ], function() {
.....
});
```

in the View all in standard. I use form:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" name="contact_us_home_form" action="{{ route('home') }}" method="post" novalidate>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

......

What is the problem?

Comment: How are you sending a request to the backend? Directly in your browser using a form? Ajax? Please update the question with how you send your request.

Comment: Do you get any output with a `dd('foo')` on the first line of `execute()`?

Comment: Yes, I get  output with a dd('foo') on the first line of execute(). 
I do not get only POST. 

Could this be related to moving the project to the host?
In fact, I just copied everything as it is, including the [vendor] folder and on the hosting server. I did not make the `composer update`  because I don`t have access to this.